# md-selected attribute(md-tabs) doesnot update after new values in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am having API response which displays the data and set the index, but after next API call the selectedIndex doesnot get updated in view(gets updated in controller)

```
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-selected="selectedIndex">

        <md-tab label="{{values.name}}" id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="values in array_list">

        </md-tab>

    </md-tabs>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in the console.

Comment: Add some more code for better understanding